# Combine two graphs of two dataframe into one graph

Tags: python, pandas

I want to combine two graphs into one graph.
I think it is quite simple but I could not figure it out. haha..

`sns.countplot(x=low_tenure.Partner)`

[image]

`sns.countplot(x=high_tenure.Partner)`

[image]

so I could compare two graphs

Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot them altogether using `seaborn`, you'd better combine two DataFrames first.

```
low_tenure['cat'] = 'Low tenure'
high_tenure['cat'] = 'High tenure'
df_combined = pd.concat([low_tenure, high_tenure])
sns.countplot(x='Partner', hue='cat', data=df_combined)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use common axis.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

sns.countplot(data1, ax=ax)
sns.countplot(data2, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me! have a great day :)